# Android Compose setupWithNavController

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I am looking for a Compose variant of [setupWithNavController(Toolbar, NavController)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#setupWithNavController(androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar,%20androidx.navigation.NavController)) to automatically update the up button in an `AppBar` whenever the Navigation destination changes.
So far I haven't found anything useful.

Is it considered a bad design in Compose? Or is there some simple way how to achieve the same thing that I am not seeing?

Comment: Did you check https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I did but they only discuss Integration with the bottom nav bar (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav). I've used it as an inspiration for integration with `TopAppBar` but the result is far from perfect.

Answer (score 6):

I've hacked up a solution, but I am not satisfied.

---

`androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha08` provides an extension function to observe the *current* back stack entry.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun NavController.currentBackStackEntryAsState(): State<NavBackStackEntry?>
```

I've created a similar extension to observe the *previous* back stack entry

```kotlin
/**
 * Gets the previous navigation back stack entry as a [MutableState]. When the given navController
 * changes the back stack due to a [NavController.navigate] or [NavController.popBackStack] this
 * will trigger a recompose and return the second top entry on the back stack.
 *
 * @return a mutable state of the previous back stack entry
 */
@Composable
fun NavController.previousBackStackEntryAsState(): State<NavBackStackEntry?> {
    val previousNavBackStackEntry = remember { mutableStateOf(previousBackStackEntry) }
    // setup the onDestinationChangedListener responsible for detecting when the
    // previous back stack entry changes
    DisposableEffect(this) {
        val callback = NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener { controller, _, _ ->
            previousNavBackStackEntry.value = controller.previousBackStackEntry
        }
        addOnDestinationChangedListener(callback)
        // remove the navController on dispose (i.e. when the composable is destroyed)
        onDispose {
            removeOnDestinationChangedListener(callback)
        }
    }
    return previousNavBackStackEntry
}
```

and a composable for the back button

```kotlin
@Composable
fun NavigationIcon(navController: NavController): @Composable (() -> Unit)? {
    val previousBackStackEntry: NavBackStackEntry? by navController.previousBackStackEntryAsState()
    return previousBackStackEntry?.let {
        {
            IconButton(onClick = {
                navController.popBackStack()
            }) {
                Icon(Icons.Default.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "Up button")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had to return a `@Composable (() -> Unit)?` (instead of no return value common to composable functions) because the `TopAppBar` uses the nullability to check whether to offset the title by 16dp (without icon) or by 72dp (with icon).

Finally, the content looks something like this

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MainContent() {
    val navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text("Weather") },
                navigationIcon = NavigationIcon(navController)
            )
        },
    ) {
        NavHost(
            navController,
            startDestination = "list"
        ) {
            composable("list") {
                ...
            }
            composable("detail") {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

List:
[image: list]

Detail:
[image: detail]

It might be cleaner to create a custom `NavigationTopAppBar` composable and hoist the `NavController` out of `NavigationIcon` but the idea stays the same. I didn't bother tinkering further.

---

I've also attempted to automatically update the title according to the *current* NavGraph destination. Unfortunately, there is not a reliable way to set a label to destinations without extracting quite a big chunk of internal implementation out of `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose` library.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the Up button like @Antimonit shows, or this simplified version that does not use the custom previousBackStackEntryAsState() function:

```
@Composable
fun NavigationIcon(navController: NavController) {
   val backStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
   val x = backStackEntry?.destination  // Triggers recomposition

   if (navController.previousBackStackEntry != null) {
      IconButton(onClick = {
         navController.navigateUp()
      }) {
         Icon(Icons.Default.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "Up")
      }
   }
}
```